# One-to-One Relationship with Hibernate-JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-5

I am having the following error when committing an Entity. According to error I have to assign an id for the Entity but I am expecting it has to be handled by JPA itself.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): alarm.ServiceAlarmConfEntity
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at alarm.Test.main(Test.java:32)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): alarm.ServiceAlarmConfEntity
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
```

I have two Entities having one-to-one relationship.

```
@Entity(name ="services")
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;
    @Column(name = "schemapath")
    private String schemapath;
    @Column(name = "customizedPath")
    private String customizedPath;
    @Column(name = "birimId")
    private Integer birimId;   
    @Column(name = "alarmthresholdXML")
    private String alarmthresholdXML;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "service", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ServiceAlarmConfEntity serviceAlarmConfEntity;
```

---

```
@Entity(name ="service_alarm_conf")
@Table(name = "service_alarm_conf")
public class ServiceAlarmConfEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "service_id")
    private Integer serviceId;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "alarmthresholdXML")
    private String alarmthresholdXML;
    @Column(name = "alarmCheckEnable")
    private Integer alarmCheckEnable;
    @Column(name = "alarmDataTransferTimeInSeconds")
    private Integer alarmDataTransferTimeInSeconds;
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Service service;
```

Main Class:

```
package alarm;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("alarm");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    Service service = new Service();
    service.setLabel("Test1");
    service.setBirimId(16);
    service.setSchemapath("test1");
    service.setCustomizedPath("Test1");


    ServiceAlarmConfEntity serviceAlarmConfEntity = new ServiceAlarmConfEntity();
    serviceAlarmConfEntity.setAlarmCheckEnable(1);
    serviceAlarmConfEntity.setAlarmthresholdXML("alarmThresholdXML");
    serviceAlarmConfEntity.setService(service);


    service.setServiceAlarmConfEntity(serviceAlarmConfEntity);

    tx.begin();
    em.persist(service);        
    tx.commit();
    em.close();
}
```

}

UPDATED:

ServiceAlarmConfEntity is configured as below. and it works.

```
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Service service;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is only automatically generated if it's annotated with `@GeneratedValue`. But it isn't.

EDIT:

As explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617), the standard and recommended way to have the child entity share the ID of its parent entity is the following:

```
public class ServiceAlarmConfEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer serviceId;

    @MapsId 
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private Service service;

    ...
}
```

Comment: but then wouldn't that generate two separate ID's (one for the parent and one for the child)? It looks like he wants the child's ID to match the parent's ID.

Comment: Yes, it would. The OP didn't ask about that. And given he uses a separate join column to refer to the parent, I don't see why he would want identical IDs. That said, why the association is marked insertable=false is a mystery to me, since the example code precisely tries to insert such an association. We'll have to wait for clarifications.

Comment: you are right damo. id of child Entity ServiceAlarmConfEntity has to be generated automatically.

Comment: @mmc: That we have all understood. But how do you want it to be generated? Do you want it to have an independant, generated ID just like the parent entity, or do you want ServiceAlarmConfEntity to share the same ID as its parent Service? And if the latter, why do you have a join column in ServiceAlarmConfEntity, since the primary key would also be the join column?

Comment: when persisting Service entity, I am expecting generated id of Service would be assigned automatically service_id of ServiceAlarmConfEntity.

Comment: And the presence of @Column on the ID, and the presence of insertable=false, updatable=false. Show us your updated code, and tell us precisely what happens.